# Cross domain webmethod giving 204 no content

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I have created a Webmethod in ASP.NET, and trying to access that through jQuery AJAX. When I call the Webmethod through browser it's giving a JSON result, but when I call that through jQuery AJAX it's giving "**204 no content**" in Firebug of Firefox. (My webmethod is in one domain and jQuery AJAX code is in other domain).

**JQuery Ajax Code:**

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost:1177/api/authentication/getusermenu?roleid=1",
           processData: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

**Firebug Output:**

[image: "Reload the page to get source for: (URL)"]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807753/http-get-with-204-no-content-is-that-normal

Comment: `http://*ocalhost:1177/api/authentication/getusermenu?roleid=1` hit this in browser and see what you get

Comment: Hi Jai, with that URL i am getting the JSON response

Comment: Is your server side code handling the JSONP requests correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:
1. if the webmethod is in the same application then no need to give localhost or anything.if the web method in any other machine and it is accessible then provide the 
          url: "http:///..." rather than localhost:portNo.
2. dataType: "json",

full example like below:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ABC.aspx/GetUserMenu?roleid=1",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            alert(data);
        }

        });
```